# Counting Retrieved Records from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, count, records

I just want to ask if how I may be able to create a dynamic numbering column based from what I will be retrieving from the database?

Ex.

```
Table Reservations
|ReservationNo----ClientNo------DateAdded----DateModified|
|1             |    1        |   01-01-01  |  01-01-01 |  
|2             |    2        |   01-01-01  |  01-01-01 | 
|3             |    2        |   01-01-01  | 01-01-01  | 
|4             |    2        |   01-01-01  | 01-01-01  | 
|5             |    1        |   01-01-01  | 01-01-01  | 
|6             |    3        |   01-01-01  | 01-01-01  |              
|7             |    3        |   01-01-01  | 01-01-01  | 
|8             |    2        |   01-01-01  | 01-01-01  | 
|9             |    1        |   01-01-01  | 01-01-01  | 
|10            |    1        |   01-01-01  | 01-01-01  |
```

When I execute the statement below...

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ClientNo = '1'
```

Result :

```
**Counter**-----ReservationNo----Client--------DateAdded----DateModified|
|1       |      1          |    1        |   01-01-01  |  01-01-01 |  
|2       |      5          |    1        |   01-01-01  | 01-01-01  | 
|3       |      9          |    1        |   01-01-01  | 01-01-01  | 
|4       |      10         |    1        |   01-01-01  | 01-01-01  |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're searching for the ROW_NUMBER function, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms186734.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [`row_number()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function:

```
select  row_number() over (order by ReservationNo) as Counter
,       *
from    YourTable
order by 
        ReservationNo
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need total the number of available rows in the table you fetch with each condition/query. 
If thats the case COUNT(*) OVER() will meet your requirements.

SELECT ReservationNo
       ,ClientNo
       ,DateAdded
       ,DateModified
       ,COUNT(*) OVER()
FROM Reservations
WHERE condition if required